# Excel VBA - Module wide variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have allocated my variables above the 1st sub procedure to make it available to all sub procedures. When I run my 2nd procedure I receive a 'with block variable not set' error

```
Dim CWS As Worksheet


Sub Test()

Set CWS = WB.Worksheets("Checks")

CWS.Activate
CWS.Range("M5:M16").Copy
CWS.Range("f5").PasteSpecial xlValues

CWS.Range("M19:M32").Copy
CWS.Range("f19").PasteSpecial xlValues


End Sub
```

Comment: Suggest to declare the object variable `wb` and set it to memory, e.g. via `Dim wb As WorkBook` and `Set wb = ThisWorkbook` (or just use the sheet's CodeName as reference - see VB Editor's tool window ~> `(Name)` in brackets); btw try to avoid unnecessary `Activate` and `.Select` :-)

Comment: Thanks so I need to set it in the Sub Procedure it is running, it cannot obtain that data from another Sub